# Relativity of simultaneity - invariance speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, observers

With reference to two observers moving relative to each other (e.g. one on the ground and another in a moving train), will someone explain the consequence of the invariance of the speed of light on the notion of simultaneity.

Comment: Hello! Maybe this video will help: https://youtu.be/gtrV-k7FFN8

It's a little slow, but I find it really gets the idea across quite simply!

Answer (score 1):

This might help, assuming you understand the argument for time dilation based on the different paths observers see the same light pulse taking.

The clock of the observer on the train runs slow, because he saw the light pulse go straight out and back.  His time advances a small amount.

Your clock showed a longer time interval because you saw the light pulse take a longer path, so for you, time advanced a greater amount.

In practice, this means that if you synchronise your clocks along the track and compare the time on his clock with the times on your different clocks as he passes them, his clock appears to lose time compared with your different clocks.  You define simultaneity as when the same time shows on your synchronised clocks.

OK so far?

Now he sees exactly the same as you saw if he looks at a light pulse that goes straight out and back for you.  So cutting the long story short, he sees one of your fixed clocks running slow as it passes his clocks synchronised for him.

This is only possible because as his clocks pass one of yours, each of his clocks shows you a later time than you would expect. His clocks do not appear to you to be synchronised.

Simultaneity for him is when the same time shows on his clocks - which for you, doesn't happen.

This is called the relativity of simultaneity.  Simultaneity means means different things in different inertial frames.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to Einstein's thought experiment with lightning striking the front and back of a train at the same time *according to the person on the platform*. Since the train is moving toward the front strike and away from the rear one, the light from the front strike will reach the train passenger (at the middle of the train) first. Both observers have to agree on that.

Now time is distance divided by velocity and the light from each strike travels the same distance to the center of the train. According to the classical addition of speeds, the light from the front strike is traveling faster than the light from the rear strike. Taking that into account, the passenger would find that the strikes occurred at the same time.

But in fact the light from the front and rear strikes both have the same speed. So given that they both traveled the same distance to the passenger at the same speed, therefore taking the same time to reach him, and the light from the front strike reached him first, he concludes that the front strike had to occur before the strike from the rear.

So it is the invariance of the speed of light that directly leads to the relativity of simultaneity.